# How do you allow not foreseen properties in RDF when performing Shex validation?

Tags: shex

We are creating our Shex definition files checking that some IRIs are of a given type. There is no problem with our generated code but sometimes we get files generated using Protege and most of the individuals are of type `X` plus `owl:NamedIndividual`, making our validation fail because now a given resource has 2 assertions of type `rdf:type`.

Adding `owl:NamedIndividual` to all shape checks seems like polluting the Shape definition, so how would you allow extra properties that do not conflict with your shape definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shex, by default the triple constraints are *closed* which means that a shape like:

```
:Shape {
  rdf:type [ :X ]
}
```

means that a node that conforms to `:Shape` must have exactly one `rdf:type` declaration whose value is `:X`.

If you want to allow extra values for the `rdf:type` declaration, you can express it with the keyword `EXTRA` as:

```
:Shape EXTRA rdf:type {
 rdf:type [ :X ]
}
```

The meaning now is that a conforming node must have `rdf:type :X` and can have zero or mode values for `rdf:type`.

Notice that the previous example could be defined as:

```
:Shape EXTRA a {
 a [ :X ]
}
```

In the particular case that you only want to allow an extra `rdf:type` with value `owl:NamedIndividual` you could also define it as:

```
:Shape {
 a [:X ] ;
 a [ owl:NamedIndividual] ;
}
```

or as:

```
:Shape {
 a [:X owl:NamedIndividual]{2} ;
}
```